# deploying application locally through apache2 or Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx

I have been developing a project for my college and now I want to deploy it in production so that other users can use it and concurrent request can be handled efficiently.

I have been facing problem using apache2 after specifying the path of rails folder it is not executing rails application so can anyone can help me in providing the perfect way or instructions to deploy my rails application on apache2 or Nginx.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: What does `apachectl configtest` return? Does it tell you that your syntax is OK?